# Show image in NavigationView Drawer

Tags: android, navigationview

What is the best way to do the following?

I have the typical navigationView with the options menu in order to move through the application. This menu has the profile image. So, in each activity I need the profile image.

I have to ways to get it:

1. Calling my function inside onCreate method of each activity.

   ```
   Bitmap image_profile = DBUsers.getInstance(this).getImageProfileDB(String email);
   ```

   As you can imagine I have an auxiliary class with all the DB functions.
2. Get the image in my first activity after login, and pass it as "Extra" through all my activities.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
   intent.putExtra("profile_img", image_profile);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

In the first way I have to call DB in each activity and I do not know if it is suitable only to show the image. But in the second way the Bitmap is traveling through the activities all the time.

I have to say that not all my activities has this options menu, but even so they wil have to receive the bitmap if I choose the second option. This is duw to they can call by other ways the activities which has the menu.

(By the way my DB is SQLite)

Comment: You have multiple activities with Navigation Drawer? That should not be. All the screens that are bound by the drawer should be represented by fragments or views.

Comment: Yes I know it, but it is due to I had all the activities implemented and then I have added the Navigation Drawer, and the only way to do it work is like this. I tried to do only one Navigation Drawer reusable in all the activities but all I have tried crashed. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_4Oh2FeRYs, but changing it a little bit

Comment: Well, you shouldn't store Bitmap in Db. You can pass the filepath between activities. I can advise you to refactor your code to fragment, otherwise you're digging a bigger pit.

Comment: My fail I do not store a bitmap, I store byte[], but my function to retreive it, convert it in Bitmap